# Changes to Flask index.py not loading

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi, vps

I'm working on a pretty simple web application utilizing Flask, and I'm trying to deploy it to a Digital Ocean VPS. I have it running with apache2 and WSGI. [Here's the git repo](https://github.com/christophernies/VAWomensHealth). I am terrible at devops, so I don't know why this isn't working.

In `/var/www/VAWomensHealth/` I have a folder with the flask app called `VAWomensHealth` and a `VAWomensHealth.wsgi` file that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/VAWomensHealth/")

from VAWomensHealth import app as application
#from app import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

My `index.py` file looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/feeds')
def feeds():
    return render_template('feeds.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and my `VAWomensHealth.conf` inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName bagbot.com
        ServerAdmin chris@example.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/VAWomensHealth/VAWomensHealth.wsgi
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        <Directory /var/www/VAWomensHealth/VAWomensHealth/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/VAWomensHealth/VAWomensHealth/static
        <Directory /var/www/VAWomensHealth/VAWomensHealth/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So when I go to the domain, the main site loads. And when I edit my static files or templates, those changes are immediately reflected on the domain.

However, code changes that I make to `index.py` don't seem to be taking effect (such as trying to have the index file load a different template). This is preventing me from adding other routes to my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me (but I can't test it) you have to change name `index.py` to `__init__.py`

Or you have to use `index` in `wsgi` file

```
from VAWomensHealth.index import app as application
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize I was using __init__.py - which is why my changes weren't reflected.

Comment: After I gave the answer I saw your repo and there is `__init__.py` so I known for sure the problem is in filename.